# Find point on rectangle where vector intercepts

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

I have a vector in the centre of a rectangle pointing out of the rectangle. The size of the rectangle is known. The vector is known. The magnitude of the vector is always greater than the distance to the edge of the rectangle. The diagram should explain.

[image: Diagram]

I know W, H and V. I need to find P.

How do I find the point where the vector intercepts the edge of the rectangle?

Comment: I don't see why the magnitude of the vector is important at all--just the direction; effectively it's a unit vector (i.e. in a given direction).

Comment: That's right. The magnitude isn't important

Comment: The vector serves as the hypotenuse of a right triangle.  The tangent of the direction angle of the vector is given by the ratio $ \ \frac{y}{x} \ $ (with the usual adjustment as necessary) , with x and y being the vector components.  You know one side of the right triangle, so this is essentially a trigonometry problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the center of the rectangle is at the origin and that 
$\overrightarrow v = \langle \cos \theta, \sin \theta \rangle$ Then, for some positive real number, $\lambda$,

$\lambda |\cos \theta | = \frac 12 h \quad$ or
$\quad \lambda |\sin \theta | = \frac 12 w$

So $\lambda = \dfrac{h}{2|\cos \theta |} \quad$ or
$\quad \lambda = \dfrac{w}{2|\sin \theta |}$

If you let the result of division by $0$ be $\infty$, then you can say

$$ \lambda =
   \min \left(\dfrac{h}{2|\cos \theta |}, \dfrac{w}{2|\sin \theta |} \right)$$

and the point of intersection will be  $\lambda \overrightarrow v$.

You should be able to handle what happens when the center of the circle is not the origin or when $\overrightarrow v$ is not a unit vector.